# Как скипнуть трек на пк?

Tags: python

Всем привет, сейчас пишу программу и мне нужно удаленно управлять звуком на пк.
Я нашел библиотеки которые могут изменять громкость звука, но не нашел инфы как скипать треки в браузере ? (Мне нужно не только скипать, но и кнопку назад и паузы)
Есть нужные библиотеки ?

Comment: Да. Та же самая библиотека, которой ты воспроизводишь музыку.

Answer (score -2):

```
import Keyboard

keyboard.send("next track")
```

Comment: Можно скипать, возвращать, ставить на паузу

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]